# pygame is screwing up ctypes

Tags: python, winapi, pygame, ctypes

```
import mymodule, ctypes
#import pygame

foo = ctypes.cdll.MyDll.foo

print 'success'
```

if i uncomment the `import pygame` this fails with `WindowsError: [Errno 182] The operating system cannot load %1`.  the stack frame is in ctypes python code, trying to load MyDll.  win32 error code 182 is `ERROR_INVALID_ORDINAL`.  if the pygame import is not there, the script runs successfully.

Update: If I run it outside the debugger, the %1 is filled with 'libpng13.dll', which is in the working directory and referenced by MyDll, and pygame is certainly loading some version of libpng. I have no idea how I would resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a dll conflict.  It seems that `import pygame` loads some dll that is not compatible with a dll that `MyDll` needs.
You should try to debug this with sysinternals ProcessExplorer, it can show which dlls a process has loaded; look for different dlls in both cases.

Another usefull tool to debug dll problems is the dependencywalker, from [www.dependencywalker.com](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Comment: Sounds promising, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for in ProcessExplorer.

Comment: In ProcessExplorer, you select the process that you want to examine.  Then you hit 'Ctrl+L' (View->Show Lower Pane).  Configure the lower pane so that it shows DLLs with 'Ctrl+D' (View->Lower Pane View->DLLs) and examine the dlls that the process has loaded.

Comment: sorry i was unclear: i understand how to use the tool, but I don't understand what I'm using it to look for.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that you edited your question.  Does pygame load a different version of libpng than your MyDll loads or needs?
Does it make a difference if you first load MyDll, and then import pygame?

Answer (score 2):

Update for the record: I believe there were multiple versions of libpng being loaded by different modules (pygame, and mydll).  I used multiprocessing to separate the two modules and everything's dandy.